# Java NIO2 AsynchronousSocketChannel/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel and TLS/SSL

Tags: java, java-7, grizzly, nio2

All the sources/samples on the INTERNET that available on NIO2 are without TLS/SSL support,

`java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel`
`java.nio.channels.AsynchronousServerSocketChannel`

As I understand the SSLEngine life-cycle of connection differ from AsynchronousSocketChannel.connect && AsynchronousServerSocketChanne.accept,
TLS/SSL should be encapsulated inside the AIO implementation, so how can I use them both...?
NOTE: I so in the Grizzly project a video that talk about they already implement it,
I look on the source code, but I saw AIO but not TLS/SSL integration...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The life cycle of the connection is the same: it's only a connection. However integrating the SSLEngine with non-blocking NIO is difficult enough for other reasons, such as having to write when you're supposed to be reading, and *vice versa,* and how to handle the tasks: I don't fancy trying it with Async I/O.

Comment: PS: Just noticed the bad spelling on my bounty comment, anyone know how to edit this?

Comment: I should add to my comment that I have subsequently implemented an AsyncSSLSocketChannel that uses the SSLEngine. As predicted, it wasn't easy.

Answer (score 4):

The comment on the original question is indeed correct.  [SSLEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html#wrap%28java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer%29%20%27SSLEngine%22) operates using [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) directly.

This means it is compatible with AIO.  You start by accepting a connection.  The client then connects and performs the initial write.  To determine if you have enough data buffered use the [handshake status](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.html) and [status](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngineResult.Status.html).  The engine will keep telling you "NEED_UNWRAP" if more data needs to be supplied from the other end.  So you need to keep a queue of ByteBuffer objects.  Same thing, the engine will keep telling you "NEED_WRAP" if more data needs to sent to the other end before it can continue.  You keep going until you get "Finished" from the handshake status.

I would recommend however you use something like Netty which makes this much simpler.  It should be noted that Netty did have support for AIO in the alpha stages of 4.  However, it was shown that AIO was slower than NIO.  Hence, it was removed.

However, not only will Netty make things simpler than trying to use NIO or AIO directly but will also make it easy to switch between the two if ever AIO is re-introduced.

A full example of using SSL with Netty can be found [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/securechat).

Comment: thanks for your input, I should of pointed out I know how to use SSLEngine and have an implementation working with traditional nio. The AIO version however I struggle to put any shape on the code. In my case wanted to learn how to implement an efficient AIO implementation by rolling my own. (I just need a few pointers design wise in terms of deadlocks and coordinating the completion handlers during the handshake).

Comment: Taking a look now at the old version of netty with AIO for pointers cheers.

Comment: You'll find that the code is indeed the same.  SSLHandler is a pipeline handler and is identical no matter if it's used with an NIO or AIO channel factory https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/c149f4bcc0c0d02aa1abcd5e39c155a9e598822e/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.java

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of doing TLS in Java is using SSLEngine. But that class is *seriously* hard to use. There are some tutorials around, but for a typical application, using SSLEngine should be out of the question. ByteChannel and their friends are not supported directly, and imply a lot of work.

I came across the same problem some time ago and ended up writing my own library. There are some examples out there and of course there is also the code inside projects like Netty, etc. But neither option is robust or easily reusable.

[TLS Channel](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel) wraps an SSLEngine in a ByteBuffer and allows to use it just like normal SocketChannels. AsynchronousByteChannels are a higher level abstraction that hides the selector loop; the library also supports that.